# Joomla! 3 strips non-English and special chars from URL

Tags: php, joomla, routes

I'm using Joomla! 3.3, and my actual URL is like this :

```
my_domain.com/component/newsletter/unsubscribe/email-domain.com/25
```

my Component's router.php :

```
function newsletterBuildRoute(&$query) {
    $segments = array();
    $segments[] = $query['method'];
    $segments[] = $query['email'];
    $segments[] = $query['id'];
    unset($query['method']);
    unset($query['email']);
    unset($query['contact_id']);
    return $segments;
}

function newsletterParseRoute($segments) {
    $vars = array();
    $vars['method'] = $segments[0];
    $vars['email'] = $segments[1];
    $vars['contact_id'] = $segments[2];
    return $vars;
}
```

But when I try this :

```
echo JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('email');
```

I get :

```
emaildomain.com //  '@' is stripped
```

And also when I put ***any*** non-English char in the url, It will be stripped too.

Any ideas why this is happenning ?

**P.S** : I set unicode aliases to yes in global configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the Joomla Documentation for JInput, you will see that there are filters that be added as an argument:

http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

So what you can try is the following:

```
echo JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('email', null, 'RAW');
```

I've used `null` as the second argument which is supposed to be the default value.

Comment: Thanks, according to this documentation , when using 'RAW' as third argument, No sanitation is provided. but why its replacing the first dash to colon ??

Comment: The first dash to a colon? Which dash are you referring to?

Comment: for example `example.com/component/products/email-me-alireza@example.com` is changing every time to `.../email:me-alireza@example.com...`